# Upload images using only Javascript or nodejs for client-side modification?

Tags: javascript, html, image

So I'm making a website as a tool people can use to generate some cards. Users have the option to upload their own backside of all the cards. However I can't find out how to allow them to upload their images.

> I don't want to save the uploaded image to the server, only have access to it client side.

I've looked and found many that use jQuery (don't have it, nor have I used it before).
 `<input type="file">` Doesn't work as it won't stay inside a select. `<select><option><input type="file"></option></select>` (displays outside the select, can't seem to fix that)
And even more that saves the img to the server. (I want it all client-side)

I'm using `browserify` so NodeJS modules work, but the few I've found require an `<input type="file">`. I'd share what I've tried, but I've only tried using the `<input>` method, and it failed and I don't know what else todo.

My end goal is to:

1. Upload image (can't figure out).
2. Copy image onto a pdf.
3. Allow user to download pdf.
4. Have it all client side so server doesn't need to stress itself.

Comment: To get the file , use event.target.files[0] in onchange listner for input. For pdf https://parall.ax/products/jspdf try this library

Comment: I use `pdfkit` atm but I'll checkout that pdf module. And I'm not using an `<input>` as it seems to not display properly when inside an `<option>` tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found this answer via a link inside a link inside the link @Mukund Goel's anwser (bunny trail). However I'm not accepting Mukund's due to the fact his answer didn't solve my problem.

So I found out what I needed by this: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click_method) I totally didn't think to use a *hidden* `<input>` tag.

So all I need todo is do this:
(*I'd make this a snippet but this doesn't work in snippets due to the need of <input type="file">*)

```js
    let hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hidden');
    let result = document.getElementById('result');
    let img = document.getElementById('result');
    document.getElementById('bttn').onclick = hiddenInput.click;
    document.getElementById('sel').onchange = hiddenInput.click;
    hiddenInput.onchange = function() {
      let file = this.files[0];
      if (!file.type.startsWith('image/')) return;
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) {
          aImg.src = e.target.result;
        };
      })(img);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

```html
    <input type="file" style="display:none" accept="image/*" id="hidden">
    <button id="bttn">Click Me</button>
    <select id="sel">
      <option>Or change me</option>
      <option>Choose me</option>
    </select>
    <img id="result">
```

Answer (score 1):

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/

You might want to read the above document and modify it according to your needs